# Using PHP url variables/php includes

Tags: php, include, url-routing

What I'm trying to do is to create a URL, example:

```
article.php?00001
```

Then using the following code this will include `00001` as an article within `article.php`

```
if(isset($_GET['00001'])){
    include('00001.php');
}else if(isset($_GET['00002'])){
    include('00002.php');
} else {
    include('noarticle.php');
}
```

Now, this works, and would be suitable for several articles if I just keep adding `00003`-`00010` etc, but if I intend to add MANY more articles, is there a better way of coding this without having to manually insert article numbers?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use article numbers and not search engine friendly titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it dynamic!
I would do something like this:

```
article.php?id=id_of_my_article

if(isset($_GET['id'])) include($_GET['id'].".php");
else include('noarticle.php');
```

Comment: Of course you should use the appropriate security precautions, for instance make sure that the id is a number and doesn't contain letters or special characters.
I suggest you to use the sanitize php class provided by OWASP http://www.owasp.org

Comment: Adding on from above comment, this works nicely, making my job semi automated at least! Thanks very much! Security options being looked at now, thanks

Comment: @NeilMacDonald See my below comment on one of the other answers - easiest way I know to make numeric input safe :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a database to store your articles. Have a look at http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql for a guide on how to use MySQL with PHP.

With regards to your URLs, use `article.php?id=###` then use `$_GET['id']` to determine which article is being viewed.

By including files based on user-supplied data, what if the user goes to `article.php?article` - it tries to load `article.php` which tries to load `article.php` which tries to ... you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, database wouldn't be needed as article is stored on a wordpress site. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @NeilMacDonald if you're looking to create "pretty" URLs, wordpress has that functionality built-in already ... and it uses a database with ID numbers for posts, so what you're doing seems a bit nonsensical.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained myself more clearly, I'm using wordpress custom fields to output an article number, which I can then pick up elsewhere on the site using wordpress codex. Sort on a CMS bodge for a friend.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know that it's insecure to include files simply based on url. There are other better means of doing so, as @Joe and @Angelo Cavallini wrote.
But if you are well aware of the consequences and determined to do so, you man try:
        $id = current( $_GET );
        $id && $id=intval($id);
        if( $id ){
            include( $id.'php' );
        }

Comment: I just do `$id = (int) $_GET['id']; if ($id > 0) ...` - if someone enters "23ab" it'll truncate to 23, and if someone enters "ab23" it'll go to 0 and just drop out.

Comment: yeah, the code presumes that parameter received is valid, if not, why would you include a file that doesn't exist?